# Eclipse thread names blank

Tags: eclipse

I wonder if anyone ever saw blank thread names in the Eclipse Debug view? Like in the image attached. Any way to get Eclipse to behave?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This is Eclipse Neon, fully updated as of 10/25/2016

Comment: That looks less like they're blank and more like either the color is conflicting with the background or the font isn't rendering at all. Have you tried changing WM or Eclipse themes?

Comment: Could be. A good thought. I'm using a slightly uncommon dark theme, perhaps it has not been tested as much. It does work most of the time though. I'll try it next time it happens.